# Jquery resizable does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

i am trying to use jquery-ui resizable.

here i am creating the resizable:

```
jQuery("#id404").resizable();
```

here is the div after i created the resizable.

```
<div style="right: 7px; top: 120px; left:0%; bottom:340px; position:absolute; overflow:visible; z-index:2; cursor:pointer;">
   <div 
      id="id404" 
      name="resizable_div" 
      class="ui-resizable" 
      style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;">
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001; "></div>
</div>
</div>
```

now, this does not work.

although the div becomes resizable (the handles appear, the icon changes etc) when i'm trying to resize the div box, it stays the same size no matter what i'm doing.
The resize process does occur, because while debugging this, the onStop and onStart callbacks did fire.

anyone can tell me what i did wrong?

i assume it is something to do with absolute divs.

thanks,

Tal

Comment: How are you implementing jQuery? Are you implementing the UI components? http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable

Comment: no, i'm using the jquery source code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a styling issue here. You have a container DIV with fixed High and Width. You are putting your re-sizable DIV inside it. So I think the container DIV is blocking the resize process.

Try to get rid of that DIV first to check if it's not the problem.

Comment: well i did try to create resizables from other random divs, and it did work. i'm looking for a way to make a resizable which overflows it's parent. i used to have a working version which looked about the same (structure wise). i made some changes in the structure, and it stopped working. but the changes i made were a lot higher in the structure tree. i believe it is something to do with the css styling of the widths and heights. i would appreciate it if you could take a closer look at the code and maybe figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The targeted ID takes on the parent's width and height, and yet has overflow hidden, so it cannot be resized beyond the parent's dimentsions.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand. the targeted div should be expanding (resized), and it's parent is overflow:visible. so that should be ok, or i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, found out what was the problem, but i have no idea why it happens.

well, i have atached to body:onresize event a function which draws everything from scratch.
this is because i have a full page web and every resize of the body i want it to be re-rendered.

but apparently  this event is fired every time jquery resizes the div, so it seemed like nothing happened.

for now, i'm setting a global flag "resize" when i start jquery resizing, and ordering the re-rendering function to return if this flag is up.

but i don't know why would the body's event would fire when an internal div is resized.

Comment: that's normal event propagation. you just need to stop the propagation in the resizeable, or find a different way to redraw everything (maybe you dont need to do it that way?)

Comment: @tal, it's probably easier and maybe better to use windows.resize() instead of the body.onResize.

Nevertheless, on the resize handle, you need to put 
element.resizable().on('resize', function (event) {
                        event.stopPropagation(); //prevent this event from triggering $(window).resize listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make parent div resizable and use this syntax :

```
$(selector, context).resizable({option1: value1, option2: value2..... });
```